# Formulario con base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Soy un poco novato en esto, lo que estoy intentando hacer es un formulario con varios formularios dentro y conectarlo a una base de datos en php, el problema es que si me crea un nuevo registro en la base de datos pero no me guarda los datos introducidos. Tengo el código un poco liado. Os agradezco la ayuda.

ARCHIVO index.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/gidole-regular" type="text/css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/osifont" type="text/css"/> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Domine" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Matrícula 2018/19</title>

    <script type="text/javascript"  charset="UTF-8"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mostrar(id){

            if (id == "mm") {
                $("#mm").show();
                $("#iniciacion").hide();
                $("#solfa-mi").hide();
                $("#adultos").hide();
            }
            if (id == "iniciacion") {
                $("#mm").hide();
                $("#iniciacion").show();
                $("#solfa-mi").hide();
                $("#adultos").hide();
            }
            if (id == "solfa-mi") {
                $("#mm").hide();
                $("#iniciacion").hide();
                $("#solfa-mi").show();
                $("#adultos").hide();
            }
            if (id == "otros") {
                $("#mm").hide();
                $("#iniciacion").hide();
                $("#solfa-mi").hide();
                $("#adultos").show();
            }


        }

        function mostrareniniciacion(){
            if (document.fsolfami.curso_diferente[0].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('opcionsi').style.display='block';
            } else {
            document.getElementById('opcionsi').style.display='none';
            }
        }

        function mostrarenadultos(){
        if (document.fadultos.lenguaje[0].checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('opcionsiadultos').style.display='block';
        } else {
        document.getElementById('opcionsiadultos').style.display='none';
        }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="matricula2018">
<form action="recibir.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Creo el formulario de datos de alumnos -->
    <div id="datos_alumnos">
        <form action="recibir.php" name="general" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h2>Datos alumno</h2></legend>
        <p>APELLIDOS:</br>
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" required="true" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
        </p>
        <p>NOMBRE:</br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" required="true" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"/></br>
        </p>
        <p>
            D.N.I.</br>
            <input type="text" name="dni" required="false" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></br>
        </p>
        <p>
            FECHA DE NACIMIENTO:</br>
            <input type="date" name="fecha_de_nacimiento" required="true" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
        </p>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Creo el formulario de datos de matricula -->
    <div id="datos_matricula" > 
        <form action="recibir.php" name="general">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h2>Datos matrícula</h2></legend>
        <div id="curso">
            <form action="recibir.php" method="post">
            <p><select  id="status" name="status" onChange="mostrar(this.value);" >
                <option selected="true" disabled="true" > SELECCIONE UN CURSO </option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA PARA BEBÉS I (0/1 AÑOS)</option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA PARA BEBÉS II (1/2 AÑOS)</option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA PARA BEBÉS III (2/3 AÑOS)</option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA EN MOVIMIENTO I (3/4 AÑOS - EI)</option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA EN MOVIMIENTO II (4/5 AÑOS - EI)</option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA EN MOVIMIENTO III (5/6 AÑOS - EI)</option>
                <option value="mm">MÚSICA EN MOVIMIENTO (FUERA DE LA ESCUELA)</option> 
                <option value="iniciacion">INICIACIÓN I (6-7 AÑOS. 1º PRIMARIA)</option>
                <option value="iniciacion">INICIACIÓN II (7-8 AÑOS. 2º PRIMARIA)</option> 
                <option value="solfa-mi">SOLFA-MI 1º (8-9 AÑOS)</option>
                <option value="solfa-mi">SOLFA-MI 2º (9-10 AÑOS)</option>
                <option value="solfa-mi">SOLFA-MI 3º (5º PRIMARIA)</option>
                <option value="solfa-mi">3º DE ENSEÑANZAS ELEMENTALES (5º PRIMARIA)</option> 
                <option value="solfa-mi">4º DE ENSEÑANZAS ELEMENTALES (6º PRIMARIA)</option>
                <option value="otros">CURSO DE ADULTOS</option> 
            </select>
        </p>
        </form>
        </div> 
        <!-- Creo cuatro divs para mostrar las opciones de los cuatro grupos de cursos -->
        <!-- Desde musica para bebes hasta musica en movimiento fuera de la escuela -->
        <div id="mm" class="element" style="display: none;">
            <form action="recibir.php" method="post">
            <p>
                <select name="centro" required="true" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
                    <option selected disabled="true" >INDIQUE EL CENTRO </option>
                    <option>AZUÉBAR</option>
                    <option>BEJÍS</option>
                    <option>CASTELLNOVO</option>
                    <option>CAUDIEL</option>
                    <option>CHÓVAR</option>
                    <option>GELDO</option>
                    <option>JÉRICA</option>
                    <option>SONEJA</option>
                    <option>SOR DE FERRER</option>
                    </select>
            </p>
                        <p>
                Seleccione:
                    <input type="radio" name="disponibilidad" value="FIN DE SEMANA"> <label for="disponibilidad">FIN DE SEMANA</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="disponibilidad"   value="SEMANA" > <label for="disponibilidad">ENTRE SEMANA</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="disponibilidad"  value="AMBOS" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"><label for="disponibilidad">AMBOS</label> 
            </p>
            </form>

        </div>
        <!-- Iniciacion uno y dos -->
        <div id="iniciacion" class="element" style="display: none;">
        <form action="recibir.php" method="post">
            <p>
            <select  name="instrumento" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
                <option selected disabled="true" >SELECCIONE UN INSTRUMENTO </option>
                <option>NINGUNO</option>
                <option>OBOE</option>
                <option>CLARINETE</option>
                <option>BOMBARDINO</option>
                <option>SAXOFÓN</option>
                <option>FAGOT</option>
                <option>FLAUTA</option>
                <option>TROMBÓN</option>
                <option>TROMPA</option>
                <option>TROMPETA</option>
                <option>TUBA</option>
                <option>PERCUSIÓN</option>
                <option>PIANO</option>
                <option>VIOLÍN</option>
            </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <select name="centro" required="true" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
                    <option selected disabled="true" >INDIQUE EL CENTRO </option>
                    <option>AZUÉBAR</option>
                    <option>BEJÍS</option>
                    <option>CASTELLNOVO</option>
                    <option>CAUDIEL</option>
                    <option>CHÓVAR</option>
                    <option>GELDO</option>
                    <option>JÉRICA</option>
                    <option>SONEJA</option>
                    <option>SOR DE FERRER</option>
                    </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                Seleccione:
                    <input type="radio" name="disponibilidad" value="FIN DE SEMANA"> <label for="disponibilidad">FIN DE SEMANA</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="disponibilidad"   value="SEMANA" > <label for="disponibilidad">ENTRE SEMANA</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="disponibilidad"  value="AMBOS" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"><label for="disponibilidad">AMBOS</label> 
            </p>
        </form> 
        </div>
        <!-- Desde solfa-mi 1º hasta 4º de enseñanzas elementales -->
        <div id="solfa-mi" class="element" style="display: none;">
            <form action="recibir.php" method="post" name="fsolfami">
                <p>¿Está realizando curso diferente respecto a lenguaje musical?<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="curso_diferente" value="SI"  onclick="mostrareniniciacion();" /> SI
                    <input type="radio" name="curso_diferente" value="NO"  onclick="mostrareniniciacion();" /> NO
                </p>
            </form>
            <div id="opcionsi" style="display:none;" class="element">
            <form action="recibir.php" method="post" name="fopcionsi">
                <p>Indique curso:</p>
                <p><select name="numerocurso" required="true">
                    <option selected disabled="true" > - </option>
                    <option>1º (8 - 9 años)</option>
                    <option>2º (9 - 10 años)</option>
                    <option>3º (10 - 11 años)</option>
                    <option>4º (11 - 12 años)</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <p>Indique instrumento:</p>
                <p><select name="instrumento" required="true">
                    <option selected disabled="true" > - </option>
                    <option>NINGUNO</option>
                    <option>OBOE</option>
                    <option>CLARINETE</option>
                    <option>BOMBARDINO</option>
                    <option>SAXOFÓN</option>
                    <option>FAGOT</option>
                    <option>FLAUTA</option>
                    <option>TROMBÓN</option>
                    <option>TROMPA</option>
                    <option>TROMPETA</option>
                    <option>TUBA</option>
                    <option>PERCUSIÓN</option>
                    <option>PIANO</option>
                    <option>VIOLÍN</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <p>Segundo instrumento:</p>
                    <select name="segundoinstrumento" id="segundoinstrumento" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
                    <option selected disabled="true" > - </option>
                    <option>OBOE</option>
                    <option>CLARINETE</option>
                    <option>BOMBARDINO</option>
                    <option>SAXOFÓN</option>
                    <option>FAGOT</option>
                    <option>FLAUTA</option>
                    <option>TROMBÓN</option>
                    <option>TROMPA</option>
                    <option>TROMPETA</option>
                    <option>TUBA</option>
                    <option>PERCUSIÓN</option>
                    <option>PIANO</option>
                    <option>VIOLÍN</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Curso de adultos y no cursa iniciacion en la escuela -->
        <div id="adultos" class="element" style="display: none;">
            <form action="recibir.php" method="post" name="fadultos">
            <p>¿Cursa lenguaje musical?<br />
                <input type="radio" name="lenguaje" value="SI"  onclick="mostrarenadultos();" /> SI
                <input type="radio" name="lenguaje" value="NO"  onclick="mostrarenadultos();" /> NO
            </p>
            </form>
            <div id="opcionsiadultos" style="display:none;" class="element">
            <form action="recibir.php" method="post" name="fopcionsiadultos">
            <p>Indique curso:</p>
            <p><select name="cursoadulto" required="true">
                    <option selected disabled="true" > - </option>
                    <option>1º </option>
                    <option>2º </option>
                    <option>3º </option>
                    <option>4º </option>
            </select>
            </p>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset> 
    </form>
    <!-- Cierro datos matricula -->
    </div>

    <div id="datos_tutor">
        <form action="recibir.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><h2>Datos madre, padre o tutor/a</h2></legend>
                <p>Cumplimentar sólo si el alumno es menor de edad.</p>
                <p>Apellidos: <input type="text" name="apellidostutor"  size="100%" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></p>
                <p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombretutor"  size="100%" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" ></p>
                <p>
                    <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td>Teléfono: </td>
                    <td>Email: </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="tel" name="telefono" size="50%" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="correo" size="50%"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <form action="recibir.php" name="general">
    <p>¿Está insteresado en participar en la escuela de verano?</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="escuelaverano"> SI</br>
        <input type="radio" name="escuelaverano"> NO </br>
    </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="LOPD" id="LOPD" value="SI"  onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">He leído y acepto la Política de privacidad.
        <p><input type="submit" id="enviar" class="enviar" value="Enviar" ></p></p>
    </form>
</fieldset>

<!--Este div cierra matricula2018 -->
</div>
</body>
```

ARCHIVO recibir.php

```
`<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'pass','db') or die('Error al conectarse al servidor');
    $sql="INSERT INTO tabla VALUES (null, '".$_POST["apellidos"]."','".$_POST["nombre"]."','".$_POST["dni"]."','".$_POST["fecha_de_nacimiento"]."','".$_POST["status"]."','".$_POST["centro"]."','".$_POST["disponibilidad"]."','".$_POST["instrumento"]."','".$_POST["curso_diferente"]."','".$_POST["numero_curso"]."','".$_POST["segundoinstrumento"]."','".$_POST["lenguaje"]."','".$_POST["cursoadulto"]."','".$_POST["apellidostutor"]."','".$_POST["nombretutor"]."','".$_POST["telefono"]."','".$_POST["correo"]."','".$_POST["escueladeverano"]."','".$_POST["lopd"]."')";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Error en el query database');
    mysqli_close($con);

    echo 'Los datos ingresados son:' .$_POST["apellidos"].$_POST["nombre"].$_POST["dni"].$_POST["fecha_de_nacimiento"].$_POST["status"].$_POST["centro"].$_POST["disponibilidad"].$_POST["instrumento"].$_POST["curso_diferente"].$_POST["numero_curso"].$_POST["segundoinstrumento"].$_POST["lenguaje"].$_POST["cursoadulto"].$_POST["apellidostutor"].$_POST["nombretutor"].$_POST["telefono"].$_POST["correo"].$_POST["escueladeverano"].$_POST["lopd"];  

?>´
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Donde esta la conexión a la BBDD? ¿Y la inserción? Si no nos proporcionas toda la información la respuesta no te va a servir.

Comment: perdona pensaba qie lo habia puesto

Comment: ¿Podéis ayudarme alguien porfavor?

Comment: Necesitariamos la definicion de la BBDD para ver la correspondencia de datos entre lo introducido y lo espereado. Aparte, ¿que quieres decir con me crea registro pero sin datos?

Comment: @JDev adjunto  una captura de pantalla con todos los campos de la base de datos y las tres filas nuevas en blanco

Comment: Necesitamos la información de la estructura de los campos no los datos insertados.

Comment: @JDev adjunto información de la estructura

Comment: Adjunta el script de creación

Comment: No lo Tengo, la he creado yo manualmente